# How to model this particular screw?

Tags: modeling, screw-modifier

I cannot model this simple thing. This is the closest I could get:

[image]

I tried the screw modifier with simple deform to taper the worm, but it didn't work. I ended up using a lattice modifier, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: you could use the Screw tool in Edit mode, in the T menu > Tools > Screw, very easy to use

Comment: @moonboots Is that different from the screw modifier?

Comment: yes, explanation below, tell me if my explanation is clear enough and if it satisfies your needs  ;)

Comment: the blender documentation is quite extensive on the Screw tool and details how it differs from the Screw Modifier(I had no idea) [link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/screw.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if you could do it properly with the Screw modifier, anyway, when you are in *Edit* mode, there's a *Screw* tool available on the T menu that works perfectly:

Draw your profile, keep in mind that the origin point will be the centre of the rotation and that the angle between the top and the bottom vertices will determine the slope of the screw. Stay in an orthogonal view so that Blender knows how it has to rotate, then click on *Screw* and play with the parameters on the bottom of the N menu.

In 2.8 it looks like you need to find the tool by the search menu (<kbd>F3</kbd>), and the parameters are in the *Operator* box (bottom left of your 3D view).

[image]

Comment: This was really helpful. Though joining the end point didn't go smooth, but that detail won't be visible.