# How to model a uncontinuously screw like in picture

Tags: modeling

This is not a continuously screw.

Thank you for your great help. Can someone tell me how to create this style of screw?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How to model the bottle threads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119230/bottle-thread-answer-doubt https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/114765/how-to-model-spiral/114771#114771 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111834/how-to-model-this-particular-screw/111840#111840

Comment: After seeing all the relevant posts if you still struggle with modeling the screw and it's hard to figure out pls feel free to edit the question with what didn't work for you. It will likely get reopened and we'll help you with that more specific problem.

Comment: Thank you for your Links. My problem is that this screw is not a continuously screw.

Comment: @KOsmani If you use the solution given as one of the answers to your last question about this, BUT don't put 360 degrees in the Angle value of the Screw Modifier, you'll get ONE of those discontinuous threads, as in your picture you'll get one of those threads, then you can repeat the process, starting at right angles to the first thread, and so on.  You need an angle of maybe 120 degrees.

Comment: @Susan is it possible, if you add some screenshots?

Comment: @KOsmani
I was basing my comment on the first answer to the question linked to below

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads

If you go through that, but use 120 instead of 360 in the Screw Modifier's angle, you'll get one of those "broken" threads.  

I could give you additional screenshots if you tell me what part of that answer, specifically, you need help with.

Comment: @Susan This method doesn't work, because all stripes are on the same height. :(

Comment: @KOsmani It works for making one stripe, with 360 changed to,for example, 120. Then you make another one, the same way, starting at the same height but at a third of the way around the cylinder. And then another.

Comment: @Susan and this is the moment that i need screenshots. Sorry i dont know how to do this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you do what is done in the first answer to this question:

[How to model the bottle threads?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50102/how-to-model-the-bottle-threads)

Because you want about 3 short threads all starting from the top, make a cylinder with the number of sides being divisible by 3, for example 33.  The cylinder in the first screen shot only has 32 sides, so the picture is only approximate.  Where the user, Xtremity, makes his single thread from one poly only, you need three, situated as shown in the first screen shot.  But make the threads one at a time.

Follow that answer/tutorial that Xtremity wrote, with only the following changes as shown in the second screen shot.  Put about 100-120 in the **Angle** of the Screw modifier, and change the value in **Screw** until your thread has a much height as you think it should have.  Iterations should stay on 1.

[image]

[image]